# Multiple Solr One Application Server (Jboss 7.1)

Tags: solr, jboss7.x

Is it possibile to have multiple Solrs in the same application server?

If yes, how can I do it?

Im in need of 3 Solr instance and I want them running at the same application server.

Im using Solr 3.6 and Jboss 7.1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically depends on what exactly your requirement is.

If your requirement is just to have 3 separate indexes to search upon 3 different modules within a single application, you could probably go with multiple cores in same Solr server.
Refer http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin for more details regarding Solr cores.

If you are planning to host a separate search server for 3 independent applications, then I would suggest you go with 3 Solrs on different ports, as given in above answer.

Comment: I still dont know how to make 3 solrs on differente ports, but I think that the Core thing will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can deploy them on different ports.

```
http://localhost:8080/solr1

http://localhost:8081/solr2

http://localhost:8082/solr3
```

and so on.

Check out the instructions from this link http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJBoss

Comment: Can you be more especific?